# SSL x509 returning null - jetty server

Tags: ssl, jetty

I have a code base which automatically invokes sslcontextfactory of jetty.util package.

I have set the keystorepath,password, truststorepath and truststore password and it is able to pick it up on my local and print x509 and the respective paths.

However, when i push this to my dev environment, the x509 prints as self and the keystorepath and truststorepath are null.

What is this issue?

Comment: Use `server.setDumpAfterStart(true)` and verify your configuration of the `SslContextFactory` (you are likely not referencing the keystore path properly)

Comment: thank you. I am refercing it as /opt/filename.jks.. this has been added to our base image..  this service is running on ecs.. should i add file:///?